# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tkinter' en vscodium

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

Soy nueva en Linux, en VSCodium y Python 3.

El problema que tengo es que me sale el siguiente error:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tkinter'
```

Hasta ahora lo tengo todo instalado:
Linux Mint, python3, VSCodium y he empezado mi primer programa:

```py
import tkinter as tk 
root = tk.Tk()  
label = tk.Label(root, text="Hello World!") # Create a text label 
label.pack(padx=20, pady=20) # Pack it into the window  
root.mainloop()
```

He instalado el módulo tk de la siguiente forma:

```
sudo apt-get install python3-tk
```

Y, por si acaso:

```
sudo apt install python3 python3-pip python3-venv
```

He comprobado que está instalado:

```
apt policy python3 python3-tk python3-venv
```

Todo parece ok pero el error sigue siendo el mismo:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tkinter'
```

Es como si VSCodium no reconociera que esos moódulos están instalados. Es posible que tenga que configurar algo en el VSCodium?

Gracias.

Comment: Te puede ayudar esta entrada https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34399387/linux-mint-17-tkinter-not-installed

Comment: En [es.so] no son necesarios los saludos :) Pon en el título de la pregunta el problema que estás teniendo. Lee [ask].

Comment: ¿Qué versión de Python arroja la terminal cuando escribís `python -V`? (con V mayúscula)

Comment: @padaleiana Yo creo que los saludos están buenos, es una forma de ser amable c: El problema es que el titulo debería ir directo al grano, no saludar. Para mi, si el saludo está en el cuerpo de la pregunta no tiene nada de malo. He aceptado ediciones donde quitan los saludos, pero solo por que también hacian otros cambios importantes.

Comment: @DanteS. Fijate en [este post en Meta](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/3415/por-qu%c3%a9-combaten-los-buenos-modales-en-so). No es que en sí sea malo.

Comment: @padaleiana entiendo que un "buen dia" o "gracias" es ruido en la pregunta, pero eso no debería tirar abajo la amabilidad. IMHO como ruido, es muy poco. Pero no entraré en discusión. A veces no estoy de acuerdo con la comunidad, y hacer un post en meta sobre el tema no me llevará a ningún lado.

Comment: Puede que esto te pueda ayudar https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-python/issues/10433

Comment: Buenos días. Procuraré saludar dentro de los cuerpos en vez de en los títulos. Reconozco que no he leído la forma de hacer preguntas, porque me parecía algo obvio, pero le echaré un vistazo, lo prometo.

Comment: Tengo la versión 3.8 de python3 y ahora mismo voy a revisar los post que me habéis enviado Vicent y Taehyung95. Buf, qué nombres ponéis, jejeje. Un saludo a todos

Comment: He revisado los dos link y los dos me dicen que instale el python3-tk. Voy a probar a hacerlo directamente, a ver si es un problema de VSCodium. Gracias por todo

Comment: Es extraño porque tkinter debería venir incluido con la instalación por defecto de python. Aparte VSCodium (o cualquier otro IDE) no influye en si un modulo está o no está, eso le pertenece a la instalación de python. Otra cosa es que VSCodium esté intentando lanzar tu script con una version distinta a la que tiene por defecto el sistema. En la esquina inferior izda debería decirte la versión de python que está configurada y pinchando deberías ver un desplegable con todas las versiones detectadas. Puedes probar también a ejecutar tu script desde consola sin pasar por VSCodium

Comment: El problema lo tengo cuando abro el programa desde VSCodium.
Si ejecuto el programa desde la terminal, no hay problema, funciona correctamente.
Voy a ver si con VS Studio también lo hace. Os mantengo informados.
Y probaré lo que me has dicho Jose Rodriguez. A ver qué se piensa codium que tiene, jejeje